# Dynamic importing of modules which contain relative imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Here's the setup:

```
 program [root]
  ├─ main.py
  ├─ utils
  |   |
  |   └─ util1.py
  └─ plugins
      |
      └─ plugin1.py
```

Now I want to load all plugins dynamically, with `pkgutil.iter_modules()`, which works fine. Until I put `from ..utils import util1` in plugin1. Then I get

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I tried two things. First, I used `importer.find_module().load_module()` like so:

```
for importer, module_name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(plugins.__path__):
    importer.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
```

and since `__package__` was empty in plugin1, I also tried `importlib.import_module()` like so:

```
module = importlib.import_module(package + "." + module_name, package=package)
```

with `package` starting as `"plugins"` and adding every sub-folder of `plugins` to the string, seperated with a `.`

Any ideas how I could make this work?